# How to generate a pull request for the local Git changes in VS2015 working against the on premises TFS?

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, pull-request

We have:

1. On premises Team Foundation Server
2. So far we have used TFS for all our repositories, but now we would like to create new projects using git.

Please, observe:

[image]

My question is about the Pull Requests:

[image]

But, when I click the Pull Requests button it takes me to the browser to the remote version of the repository. Of course, it does not have my local changes (after all, they are local) and so I am kind of puzzled how am I supposed to produce a Pull Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to push your local branch to the remote in order to open a pull request. That's how pull requests work in every Git hosting platform that offer a pull request feature.

The idea is that you work locally in your own branch. When you're done working, you share the branch with the rest of the team and open a PR to signal that you'd like it reviewed and merged into a stable branch.

Once the PR is completed, the branch can be deleted both on the remote and on your local.

Comment: I know this is how it works on Github, but I did not think the Team Foundation Server works this way too. So, we should have a golden repo and then another repo being the fork of the golden and to which all the devs on the team synchronize?

Comment: You should choose an appropriate branching model such as GitFlow. You don't need to maintain forks of repositories.

Comment: I found this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/03/20/gated-checkin-for-git-using-branch-policies-to-run-a-build-in-vsts-and-tfs/ So, I should use two branches in the same repository - one to push to, then through PR to sync it with another one and to pull from the latter. Something like that?

Comment: @mark Yes. The GitFlow branching model is very popular and works well for most scenarios; I'd recommend looking it up.